# What is the use of hexadecimal values in programming?

Tags: hex, cpu-word

This is something I have been thinking while reading programming books and in computer science class at school where we learned how to convert decimal values into hexadecimal.
Can someone please tell me what are the advantages of using hexadecimal values and why we use them in programmnig?
Thank you.

Comment: I can only think of colors, which leads me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383415/why-use-base16-numbers-in-code-when-base10-numbers-are-more-readable).

Comment: @DaveChen - hex basically just makes it a lot easier to manage binary numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases (like e.g. bit masks) you need to use binary, but binary is hard to read because of its length. Since hexadecimal values can be much easier translated to/from binary than decimals, you could look at hex values as kind of shorthand notation for binary values.

Comment: Would this mean hexadecimal values are more efficient than using decimal?

Comment: @Ethylene - no, it just makes them a LOT easier for humans to manage. EDIT: I guess that would make it more efficient from a human's perspective, but at the hardware level of computing, can't get more efficient than binary

Answer (score 0):

It certainly depends on what you're doing.
It comes as an extension of base 2, which you probably are familiar with as essential to computing.

Check this out for a good discussion of 
several applications...

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170440/why-use-other-number-bases-when-programming/

Comment: Wikipedia sums the use of hexadecimal up very well: `[Its primary use] is a human-friendly representation of binary-coded values in computing and digital electronics`

Answer (score 0):

The hexadecimal digit corresponds 1:1 to a given pattern of 4 bits. With experience, you can map them from memory. E.g. 0x8 = 1000, 0xF = 1111, correspondingly, 0x8F = 10001111.
This is a convenient shorthand where the bit patterns do matter, e.g. in bit maps or when working with i/o ports. To visualize the bit pattern for 169d is in comparison more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

A [byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) consists of 8 binary digits and is the smallest piece of data that computers normally work with. All other variables a computer works with are constructed from bytes. For example; a single character can be stored in a single byte, and a 32bit integer consists of 4 bytes.

As bytes are so fundamental we want a way to write down their value as neatly and efficiently as possible. One option would be to use binary, but then we would need a lot of digits. This takes up a lot of space and can be confusing when many numbers are written in sequence:

```
200 201 202 == 11001000 11001001 11001010
```

Using hexadecimal notation, we can write every byte using just two digits:

```
200 == C8
```

Also, as 16 is a power of 2, it is easy to convert between hexadecimal and binary representations in your head. This is useful as sometimes we are only interested in a single bit within the byte. As a simple example, if the first digit of a hexadecimal representation is 0 we know that the first four binary digits are 0.