# How do computers store hex numbers?

Tags: hex

I'm trying to understand some basic computer science. About hex and binary. I don't have any problems with the maths. I understand that one reason to use hex is that it is easier for work with than binary. But I am confused about how hex numbers are actually stored in memory.

For example; 245 in base 10 is F5 in hex and 11110101 in binary.

How is this hex number actually stored in memory? Does it use one byte or two? Is it simply converted into the binary, in which case the point about hex is simply for human convenience, or is actually stored in a different way?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean as a string? Or as a raw number?

Comment: @harold I wish I knew. I think this is the point I am confused about. Could you explain both? I guess if raw number it looks the same. The F is 1111 and 5 is 0101? If string then it needs two bytes - an ascii binary F and an ascii byte for the string 5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do Computers use Hex Number System at assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198530/why-do-computers-use-hex-number-system-at-assembly-language) , or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689182/what-is-the-use-of-hexadecimal-values-in-programming

Comment: hex is for humans only, the compiler does the math, every number is stored binary

Comment: found a link confirming that: https://superuser.com/questions/1175060/hexadecimal-format-and-storage-on-a-computer-hard-drive-does-it-store-in-half-t

Comment: @Renat - those links seem to answer the question. Thank you.